# Vagrant start docker image on existing machine

Tags: docker, vagrant

I am trying to start docker container on running aws machine with Vagrant. My files are

DockerHostVagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "my-key.pem"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.host = "something-141.compute.amazonaws.com"
  config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
  config.ssh.shell = "echo hello >> hello.txt"
end
```

Vagrantfile

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "redis" do |v|  
    v.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.name = "gitlab-redis"
      d.image = "sameersbn/redis:latest"
      d.volumes = ["/srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis"]
      d.vagrant_machine = "dockerhost"
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./DockerHostVagrantfile"    
    end
  end  

end
```

Then I run

```
vagrant up
```

And error is

```
Bringing machine 'redis' up with 'docker' provider...
==> redis: Creating the container...
    redis:   Name: gitlab-redis
    redis:  Image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    redis: Volume: /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis
    redis: Volume: /home/kafkapre/tmp/Vagrant:/vagrant
A Docker command executed by Vagrant didn't complete successfully!
The command run along with the output from the command is shown
below.

Command: ["docker", "run", "--name", "gitlab-redis", "-d", "-v", "/srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis", "-v", "/home/kafkapre/tmp/Vagrant:/vagrant", "sameersbn/redis:latest", {:notify=>[:stdout, :stderr]}]

Stderr: Unable to find image 'sameersbn/redis:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/sameersbn/redis
/usr/bin/docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/sameersbn/redis/images: remote error: access denied.
```

I am sure that I mistake is in DockerHostVagrantfile, but I have no idea. If I would to connect to machine via ssh directly. I would write:

ssh -i my-key.pem ubuntu@something-141.compute.amazonaws.com

Any idea how to do it via Vagrant? Thanks.

Comment: whats the docker version on your amazon machine ?

Comment: Hi Docker version is 1.11.1 - Ubuntu 14.04 64bit